# SSRS Tablix (Expand Collapse)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a tablix that pivots data in the following way

```
Agent   Brochure1   Brochure2   Brochure3
xyz     10          15          25
```

The client wants a total column for all the brochure and the ability to expand the total to display the individual quantities.  e.g.

```
Agent   Total
xyz     50

Agent   Total  Brochure1   Brochure2   Brochure3
xyz     50     10          15          25
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use expand/collapse actions horizontally. Is your tablix a matrix and brochure values are being calculated from Column Groups or Brochure1, Brochure2 and Brochure3 are fields in your dataset?

Comment: They are column groups.  All the brochure are passed in via tsql and the data is pivoted and calculated

Comment: In that case I think it is not possible using `ToggleItem` property (expand/collapse action). A workaround could be use a parameter to ask user if he/she wants to hide the Brochure columns or not. If that works for you let me know